# Using liquid sandpaper (deglosser) with polyurethane varnish

Tags: polyurethane

Revarnishing kitchen cabinets, using polyurethane (oil base) over existing varnish.  Can I use liquid sandpaper to degloss the old varnish?  What about in between coats of the new?  Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that deglosser is good for cleaning and prepping a surface, equivalent to scuffing the existing finish so the new finish will adhere better. It's primary use is cleaning off anything that would interfere with your next coat, like grease. It is not really a stripper.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **after sanding** you can use the liquid deglosser for a final wipe down and cleaning prior to applying fresh coats of varnish. Using it alone in lieu of sanding is not a good idea IMO.

Do not use it between coats, just give a real quick fine sanding (or steel wool) and wipe down with a damp cloth or tack cloth.

Use outdoors or with good ventilation as that stuff is a volatile solvent.